# Trying to write output to a CSV on a directory, failing with PLS-00302

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, utl-file

I'm attempting to output some monitoring information into a .csv file. I have to stick with the "Basic" framework of the code. The issue is getting it to output to .csv/getting the code to compile.

I've tried various ways of doing this, now I'm stuck I mostly find myself moving quotes and double quotes around.

```
create or replace procedure WRITE_EST_SIZE_01 is
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
begin
  file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', 
                                'csv_filename' || 
                                   to_char(sysdate,'MONYYYY')||'.csv',
                                'w', 32767);
  for rws in (SELECT 'OWNER' || ',' || 
                     'SEGMENT_NAME' || ',' ||
                     'U' || ',' ||
                     'SUM_BYTES'
                FROM
              union ALL
              select /*+ parallel*/
                     s.owner || ',' ||
                     s.segment_name || ',' ||
                     'U' || ',' ||
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s
                where s.owner = (select distinct targetschema
                                   from pdu.pdu_table) and
                      s.segment_name in (select table_name
                                           from another_table) and 
                      s.segment_type LIKE '%TABLE%'
                group by s.owner, s.segment_name
              union all
              select /*+ parallel*/
                     i.table_owner || ',' || 
                     i.table_name || ',' ||
                     'I' || ',' ||
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s,
                     DBA_INDEXES  i
                where i.table_owner  = (select distinct targetschema
                                          from pdu.pdu_table) and
                      i.table_name in (select table_name
                                         from another_table) and
                      i.owner = s.owner and
                      i.index_name = s.segment_name and
                      s.segment_type like '%INDEX%'
                group by i.table_owner, i.table_name
              union all
              select /*+ parallel*/
                     l.owner || ',' ||
                     l.table_name || ',' ||
                     'L' || ',' ||
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s,
                     ALL_LOBS l
                where l.owner = (select distinct targetschema
                                   from another_table) and
                      l.table_name in (select table_name
                                         from another_table) and
                      l.owner = s.owner and
                      l.segment_name = s.segment_name
                group by l.owner, l.table_name
                --order by 1, 2)
  loop
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                      rws.SEGMENT_NAME || ',' ||
                      rws.U || ',' ||
                      rws.SUM_BYTES -- your columns here
                      );
  end loop;

  utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end WRITE_EST_SIZE_01;
```

This actually won't compile, but complains that rws.OWNER should be declared. It compiles if I put all the rws. in quotes, but then the csv output is overwritten with whatever is in quotes. Can anyone see a way of doing this whereby it actually "Will" dump the output of the sql to a .csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL you're creating a concatenated string when it appears you just wanted to fetch the individual fields. I suggest:

```
create or replace procedure WRITE_EST_SIZE_01 is
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
begin
  file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', 
                                'csv_filename' || 
                                   to_char(sysdate,'MONYYYY')||'.csv',
                                'w', 32767);
  for rws in (select s.owner,
                     s.segment_name,
                     'U' AS FLAG,
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s
                where s.owner = (select distinct targetschema
                                   from pdu.pdu_table) and
                      s.segment_name in (select table_name
                                           from another_table) and 
                      s.segment_type LIKE '%TABLE%'
                group by s.owner, s.segment_name
              union all
              select i.table_owner AS OWNER,
                     i.table_name AS SEGMENT_NAME,
                     'I' AS FLAG,
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s,
                     DBA_INDEXES  i
                where i.table_owner  = (select distinct targetschema
                                          from pdu.pdu_table) and
                      i.table_name in (select table_name
                                         from another_table) and
                      i.owner = s.owner and
                      i.index_name = s.segment_name and
                      s.segment_type like '%INDEX%'
                group by i.table_owner, i.table_name
              union all
              select l.owner,
                     l.table_name AS SEGMENT_NAME,
                     'L' AS FLAG,
                     sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 AS SUM_BYTES
                from DBA_SEGMENTS s,
                     ALL_LOBS l
                where l.owner = (select distinct targetschema
                                   from another_table) and
                      l.table_name in (select table_name
                                         from another_table) and
                      l.owner = s.owner and
                      l.segment_name = s.segment_name
                group by l.owner, l.table_name
                --order by 1, 2)
  loop
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                      rws.SEGMENT_NAME || ',' ||
                      rws.FLAG || ',' ||
                      rws.SUM_BYTES -- your columns here
                      );
  end loop;

  utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end WRITE_EST_SIZE_01;
```

Comment: You could add `utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,U,SUM_BYTES');` before the loop to generate the header row?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks Alex. It compiles, until I add in the utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,U,SUM_BYTES'); before the loop. Is that supposed to go in, just stand alone, or am I meant to remove a bit before adding that in?

Comment: @Dave - I didn't mean immediately before they keyword `loop`, I meant tbefore the whole loop structure - so it goes between the `utl_file.fopen(...);` and `for rws in ...`.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Thanks Alex I have this working now. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Your cursor query is doing the concatenation in each branch of the union, so if you ran that standalone you'd see a result set with a single column. When you try to process the loop you're trying to look for the individual owner/segment/etc. - but they are not part of the projection from that cursor query.

If you give the single generated column value an alias, in at least the first branch:

```
SELECT 'OWNER'||','||'SEGMENT_NAME'||','||'U'||','||'SUM_BYTES' AS CSV_TEXT
```

or more simply:

```
SELECT 'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,U,SUM_BYTES' AS CSV_TEXT
```

then in your loop you can refer to that alias:

```
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, rws.CSV_TEXT);
```

Although it would probably be simpler just to write the header row out to the file directly before your cursor loop, instead of making it part of that query:

```
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,U,SUM_BYTES');
```

You could then keep the concatenation in the remaining union branches with the same single column-value alias; or have the union branches get the raw columns (owner etc.) without concatenating, and then keep the concatenation inside the loop. [As @BobJarvis' answer is doing!] But don't do both...

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
   ) loop
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, rws.OWNER||','||rws.SEGMENT_NAME||','||rws.U||','||rws.SUM_BYTES);
```

you use column names which should be described in the query inside `for rws in (select ...) loop`. Currently, that `SELECT` statement has only one column whis automatically generated name. You need to change it to:

```
SELECT 'OWNER' owner, 'SEGMENT_NAME' segment_name, 'U' u, 'SUM_BYTES' sum_bytes
  FROM dual
 union all
select /*+ parallel*/
       s.owner, s.segment_name, 'U', sum(s.bytes)/1024/1024 
  from ...
```

Also, you need to change all other subqueries in this way.

Or, you can keep this query as is, except a small change:

```
for rws in (SELECT 'OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,U,SUM_BYTES' row_data
                FROM
              union ALL
```

And change the last line:

```
...
) loop
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, rws._row_data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this. Great work and very helpful.